# Does weaviate support dot product similarity when using the python sdk

Tags: weaviate

I have saved vectors in Weaviate that I want to query using dot product.
I'm using the python sdk and I just don't see anyway of specifying this.
Does anyone know if this is possible/not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi and thanks for your question.

The simple answer as of writing this is "not yet, but soon", but I think I need to elaborate a bit to explain more.

### Distance Functions

Generally, distance functions in Weaviate are entirely pluggable. Anything that can produce a score can be plugged in. For example, [see this folder](https://github.com/semi-technologies/weaviate/tree/master/adapters/repos/db/vector/hnsw/distancer). In fact, you will even see a file named `dot_product.go` in there. This is because internally for calculating the cosine sim, Weaviate will normalize all vectors on read and then just calculate the dot product.

### APIs

So, if Weaviate can calculate the dot product why can't you select this option? This is because of a past decision to introduce the `certainty` field in the API. This field is used to return scores and to limit results by score. The original idea behind the certainty was that we would want a single metric that can produce a number between `0` and `1` to indicate the distance. With cosine sim that's simple, as this is already in the range of `-1, 1`, so it's very easy to transform it into a certainty. With an unbounded score such as dot product, this isn't so easy.

### Path forward

Here [is a discussion on this topic](https://github.com/semi-technologies/weaviate/issues/1863). Feel free to participate in this discussion. The current favorite option is to deprecate `certainty` and expose the raw values as either `score` or `distance`.

### Any quickfixes?

We could easily enable new distance scores, such as dot product before the above mentioned API issue is solved. Possibly as an experimental feature using a feature flag. However, you would not be able to see the resulting scores/distances in the APIs.

### Timelines

I expect the above mentioned issue to be resolved in a couple of weeks as of writing this (April 28, 2022).